# PTR lookup to authenticate emails

Tags: domain-name-system, ptr-record

gmx.com and mail.com are using PTR lookup to authenticate emails. For example, I used 1.1.1.1 to send email as from gmail.com to gmx.com, gmx.com would do PTR look up for 1.1.1.1 see if its gmail.com.

My question is if someone is using cloud-based service, which means A.com's email would be sent by other domains' server. Would it fail authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Forward-confirmed reverse DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS) is used as a basic mechanism to prevent spoofing of the host rather than the email domain.  It's not related to the email 'From' field.

So in your example, when you attempt to send email from 'gmail.com', your sending mail server opens the conversation by declaring *its own hostname*

```
helo mailserver.domain.com
```

the recipient mail server uses the PTR lookup to make sure that 'mailserver.domain.com' is associated with 1.1.1.1.  You can then use any 'mail from:' - this isn't what the PTR lookup is intended for.

The sending domain / mail from can be checked using other anti-spam methods such as DKIM, SPF and DMARC, but it's not related to the PTR lookup that some mailservers implement.